# Disable Sorting in excel

Tags: excel, sorting

I have an excel document with many columns and many rows filled with data.
I want to be prevent user for sorting the data completely, but user should be able to insert and delete row as they wish.  They can also edit any cells that they want.

May I know if there is anyway to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: But surely the user could row insertion and deletion along with editing to implement a sorting?

Comment: yes, agree.  But we would like to disable sorting feature in order to prevent significant changes to the spreadsheet...

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work-

Protect the worksheet and check all the option other than the Sort and autofilter and you should be good to go.